# Java pattern match for cisco configuration line

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a text cisco configuration.
The hostname line I should match is "**125-hostname billdevice**".
I am using below pattern but not matching true.

```
Pattern ciscohostname = Pattern.compile("^[0-9999999]-hostname");
Matcher matcherx = ciscohostname.matcher(BlockIndexList.get(k).toString());
```

How can I match this line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is

```
"^[0-9]+-hostname"
```

This means: 
Match if string starts with **at least one** character in range of [0-9](aka. digits) followed by string "-hostname"

Answer (score 0):

As you've specified a range in your code (i.e., 0-9999999) then you can use this RegEx

```
^[0-9]{1,7}-hostname
```

This will ensure that only 1 to 7 digit numbers are matched and any number more than that will be eliminated.

```
0-hostname billdevice          //match
9999999-hostname billdevice    //match
10000000-hostname billdevice   //no match
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/ylYWw4/1)